# AEM Solr integration

Tags: solr, aem

I'm following this mini [tutorial](http://www.aemsolrsearch.com/#/getting-started) on how to integrate Solr on a local AEM instance.
I get stuck on point 5: whene I try to connet to localhost:8080/solr/ I receive the following error code:

```
{msg=SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: Could not load core configuration for core collection1,trace=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: Could not load core configuration for core collection1
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:753)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:307)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:207)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1125)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1059)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:485)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:290)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:248)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:606)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:535)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load core configuration for core collection1
at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSetService.getConfig(ConfigSetService.java:66)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:554)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:261)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:253)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.<init>(IndexSchema.java:168)
at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchemaFactory.create(IndexSchemaFactory.java:55)
at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchemaFactory.buildIndexSchema(IndexSchemaFactory.java:69)
at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSetService.createIndexSchema(ConfigSetService.java:89)
at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSetService.getConfig(ConfigSetService.java:62)
... 9 more
Caused by: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:277)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:338)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:317)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.WordlistLoader.getLines(WordlistLoader.java:223)
at      org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.AbstractAnalysisFactory.getLines(AbstractAnalysisFactory.java:256)
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.AbstractAnalysisFactory.getWordSet(AbstractAnalysisFactory.java:244)
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.StopFilterFactory.inform(StopFilterFactory.java:99)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.inform(SolrResourceLoader.java:675)
at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.<init>(IndexSchema.java:166)
... 13 more
,code=500}
```

Does anyone have got any idea on how to solve it?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but there was a talk about Solr integration at the adaptTo conference last week (Slides and some sources are attached): http://adapt.to/2014/en/schedule/integrating-open-source-search-with-cq-aem.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer Thomas. I finally managed to solve the problem. I don't know exactly where is the issue, but there was somenthing broken in collection1s' files). I downloaded the last version of Solr and used the files inside <solr-dir>\example\solr\collection1\conf to overwrite the previviouses (all the files extcept the .xml(s)) So I started Solr using the start.jar inside <solr-dir>\example which instanciate Solr running at localhost:8983

Comment: Have you created the core "collection1"?